# What is the use of while({}) in javascript

Tags: javascript

`({}) === true` and `({}) == true` both return false however:

```
while({}){console.log("I'm running...")}
```

will cause cnosole.log to execute indefinitely.

How is the while loop taken if the expression equals `false` and where does this statement gets used?

Comment: an object is a truthy value, so `while({})` is the same as `while(true)`. Why you'd write the former, I've no idea as it's just more obtuse way of writing the latter.

Comment: Because `!!{}` will return `true`

Comment: but then why does `({}) == true` is false if an object is a truthy value?

Comment: welcome to javascript

Comment: For the same reason `2 == true` is false, even though 2 is truthy

Comment: You can do `Boolean({})` to see whether a value is truthy or not

Comment: @dan because truthy basically means *converts to true* not *is equal to true*

Comment: `({}) === true` is just as true as `({}) === false` ;)